# setDelegate to my custom view controller fall with unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a view controller on the StoryBoard with my custom class. Here the code:

BGMDatePickerViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//declare a protocol with name
@protocol DatePickerViewControllerDelegate        //declare a delegate so that this class can notify another class when a user selects a chart
//protocol methods
//- (void)userDataChangedWithUsername;

@end


//declare a class with inheritance
@interface BGMDatePickerViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>


//create a public property
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<DatePickerViewControllerDelegate> delegate;   //property to store the delegate


@end
```

I would like to show this ViewController on another one with delegate. Here the code:
BGMChartViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BGMDatePickerViewController.h"             

//declare a class with inheritance
@interface BGMChartViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, DatePickerViewControllerDelegate>  //conforms UIActionSheetDelegate and my custom DatePickerViewControllerDelegate protocols

//create a public IB methods
- (IBAction)showDateEntryForm:(id)sender;           

@end
```

BGMChartViewController.m

```
#import "BGMChartViewController.h"

@interface BGMChartViewController ()

//create a private properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *datePickerPopover;
@end


@implementation BGMChartViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (IBAction)showDateEntryForm:(id)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%s: has been started...", __FUNCTION__);

    BGMDatePickerViewController *datePickerVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dateEntryFormVC"];

    datePickerVC.delegate = self;   //HERE THE FALL!!!!!

    self.datePickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:datePickerVC];

    //define the popover size
    self.datePickerPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 400.0);

    //let’s display it
    [self.datePickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame]
                                            inView:self.view
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                          animated:YES];

}

@end
```

On the line which I marked it just fall with:

```
-[BGMDatePickerViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78a3bcf0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BGMDatePickerViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78a3bcf0'
```

If I comment this problem line it's ok I see my custom view controller so that means that I am ok with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier tag...
I don't understand what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Modify to the below line and check:-

```
@protocol DatePickerViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>
```

Comment: While this is a good change, it will have no affect on the error.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. Any ideas, please? ((